# how do i change the ssl PORT in lampp?

Tags: 20.04, lamp, xampp

hello i am trying to change the ssl port in Lampp

i tried to change the Port

```
if test $ssl -eq 1 && testport 6453
```

> in sudo nano /opt/lampp/lampp

and i tried to restart and encountered into an error and phpmyadmin stopped from working

```
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.40-1...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose...
XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong.
XAMPP:  Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/
Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":
tail: cannot open '/opt/lampp/logs/error.log' for reading: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```